# Performance of an OLX crawler

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I'm learning concurrency and asynchronous programming in C#. For a better grasp on the matter I'm trying to create an OLX Crawler. My issue here is the performance: It takes roughly 159 minutes to crawl 17.901 links.

The method which crawls each item is this:

```
public async Task FetchItemsData()
    {
        var itemsTask = new List<Task<string>>();
        string itemUrl = string.Empty;
        var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(150);

        while (this.queue.TryDequeue(out itemUrl))
        {
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();
            try
            {
                var source =  Task.Run( () => this.GetSource(itemUrl) );

                itemsTask.Add(source);

                await Task.Delay(1);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (itemsTask.Count == 150)
                {
                    await Task.WhenAll(itemsTask);
                    ItemSourceParser itemParser = new ItemSourceParser();

                    foreach (var task in itemsTask)
                    {
                        await task.ContinueWith(async _ =>
                        {
                            itemParser.InitializeNewItem(_.Result);
                            itemParser.TryToParse();
                            Console.WriteLine(itemParser.data["Id"]);
                            this.database.InsertItem(itemParser.data);
                            itemParser.RefreshData();
                            await Task.Delay(1);
                        });
                    }

                    itemsTask.Clear();
                }
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        }

       /* FURTHER PROCESSING */
    }
```

The queue is a `ConcurrentQueue` which holds the item string. In the `finally` block I'm trying to await 150 concurrent tasks to not overload the server.

The `GetSource` method is here:

```
public async Task<string> GetSource(string url)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
            this.ProgressUpdater.ProgressBarUpdater.Report(1);
            responseMessage.Version = HttpVersion.Version10;
            responseMessage = await this.client.GetAsync(url);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.ProgressUpdater.LogUpdater.Report("Connection timeout on: " + url + ". Retrying after 0.5 seconds");
            await Task.Delay(1500);
            this.ProgressUpdater.ProgressBarUpdater.Report(-1);
            return await this.GetSource(url);
        }
        return await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

I'm guessing that something is not right. Is there any redundant code that needs to be removed or something that I should have done so that the crawler has a better performance?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a `SemaphoreSlim` because a `Task` is not equivalent to a `Thread`. It is a more abstract kind of "working item" that will be spreaded to real threads by the TPL. If you start 1000 tasks it does not mean that you create 1000 threads. When starting a task like you did (without option TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning), it will be executed on threads from the TreadPool. Therfore, the Threadpool is managing the number of threads for you and you can just start 17.901 tasks at once.

---

What is `await Task.Delay(1)` for?

If there is no reason for it, it just produces unnecessary overhead

---

```
var source =  Task.Run( () => this.GetSource(itemUrl) );
```

You don't need to wrap the returning taks in a new task. The following has less overhead and is functional equivalent:

```
var source =  this.GetSource(itemUrl);
```

---

Move the code from the finally block to the call of `GetSourceAsync`. There is no need to attach it via `ContinueWith` in the finally block.

---

All the points above applied yields to something like:

```
async Task FetchItemsDataAsync()
{
    var itemsTask = new List<Task<string>>();
    var itemParser = new ItemSourceParser();

    while (this.queue.TryDequeue(out itemUrl))
    {
        var task = Task.Run(async() =>
        {
            var result = await this.GetSourceAsync(itemUrl);
            itemParser.InitializeNewItem(result);
            itemParser.TryToParse();
            Console.WriteLine(itemParser.data["Id"]);
            this.database.InsertItem(itemParser.data);
            itemParser.RefreshData();
        }
        itemsTask.Add(task);
    }

    return Task.WhenAll(itemsTask);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the Task.Run force the method to run in a new Thread from the Thread Pool? I would like it to run concurrently, thats why I had the SemaphoreSlim but the release is happening before the thread completes so I'm awaiting some of the tasks on the finally block.

Comment: @Zroq: "Wouldn't the Task.Run force the method to run in a new Thread from the Thread Pool?" It would force the method to run in a thread from the Thread Pool - not necessarily a new thread because the threadpool reuses threads internally. Therefore the tasks will be executed concurrently. However, the actual number of threads will be managed by the threadpool. If you require lots of thread, the threadpool creates (and releases) them internally.